# Using ag-grid react, how to select rows by default?

Tags: ag-grid-react

I need to display my table with selected rows and ticked checkboxes by default.
Was checking the ag-grid react official documentation, but couldn't find any answer for this.
I found an old post related to the topic - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165439/how-can-i-set-default-checked-in-ag-grid-react-js](https://stackoverflow.com) - but it's using class component and I need a solution for functional components

I tried to add the "cellRendererParams" prop in columnDefs but it does not work.

```
const columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'ID', field: 'id' },
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name' },
  {
    headerName: 'Select',
    field: 'selected',
    cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
    cellRendererParams: {
    checkbox: true,
  },
 },
];
```